# Android Update app with all resource without ask All vs New

Tags: android

I have created Android app a while ago.
this app use inside the company. we not uploaded to Google play store. Just install APK.

and now I updated the app with the new resource. while update app install screen ask from users to New or All

see the photo
[image]

I want to skip or hide this screen
just install all data without ask.

how can I do this?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is the *old* permissions screen.

If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower, if you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission **when they install the app;** if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.

You can't skip it.

Instead if the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher you can use the runtime permissions.

Check [here](http://Beginning%20in%20Android%206.0%20(API%20level%2023),%20users%20grant%20permissions%20to%20apps%20while%20the%20app%20is%20running,%20not%20when%20they%20install%20the%20app) for more details.